# Passing rvalue reference to const lvalue reference paremeter

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue, const-reference

I am trying to understand C++11 *rvalue references* and how to use them for optimal performance in my code.

Let's say we have a class `A` that has a member pointer to a large amount of dynamically allocated data.

Furthermore, a method `foo(const A& a)` that does something with an object of class `A`.

I want to **prevent the copy constructor of `A` from being called** when an object of `A` is passed to the function `foo`, since in that case it will perform a deep copy of the underlying heap data.

I tested passing an lvalue reference:

```
    A a;
    foo(a);
```

and passing an rvalue reference:

```
    foo(A());
```

In both cases the copy constructor was *not* called.

Is this expected or is this due to some optimization of my compiler (Apple LLVM 5.1)? Is there any specification about this?

Answer (score 21):

That is expected. If you pass an argument to a reference type parameter (whether lvalue or rvalue reference), the object will not be copied. That is the whole point of references.

The confusion you're having is pretty common. The choice of copy or move constructor only occurs when passing an object by value. For example:

```
void foo(A a);
```

When passing an `A` object to this function, the compiler will determine whether to use the copy or move constructor depending on whether the expression you pass is an lvalue or rvalue expression.

On the other hand, none of the following functions would even try to invoke the copy or move constructor because *no object is being constructed*:

```
void foo(A& a);
void foo(const A& a);
void foo(A&& a);
void foo(const A&& a);
```

It's important to note that you should rarely (if ever) have any reason to write a function, other than a move constructor/assignment operator, that takes an rvalue reference. You should be deciding between passing by value and passing by `const` lvalue reference:

1. If you're going to need a copy of the object inside the function anyway (perhaps because you want to modify a copy or pass it to another function), take it by value (`A`). This way, if you're given an lvalue, it'll have to be copied (you can't avoid this), but if you're given an rvalue, it'll be optimally moved into your function.
2. If you're not going to need a copy of the object, take it by `const` lvalue reference (`const A&`). This way, regardless of whether you're given an lvalue or rvalue, no copy will take place. You shouldn't use this when you do need to copy it though, because it prevents you from utilising move semantics.

From the sounds of it, you're not going to make any copies at all, so a `const A&` parameter would work.

Comment: I only approved [starius](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1293417/starius)' edit and made an insignificant change to it; it's his edit that matters. There should be a way to have the original editor's name on such a change.

Comment: @bogdan It shows you because you were the last person to edit, but starius is in the list of edits (if you click on the text "edited 1 hour ago").

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but still... if I knew my "improvement" would appear as a separate edit, I would have left the original change as it was. I didn't give much thought to versioning initially; in retrospect, it's pretty clear why it works the way it does - it links the two changes but doesn't merge them. Anyway, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Imagine that we have a class X, containing a vector<MyClass>. MyClass contains lots of heap-memory data. Now if I write a function `add` for the class X, I think an rvalue reference parameter is necessary. `x.add(MyClass(...))` will call that function.

Comment: **This way, if you're given an lvalue, it'll have to be copied (you can't avoid this), but if you're given an rvalue, it'll be optimally moved into your function.** - If the functions takes in param of type `A`, and I pass it a rvalue of type `A&&`, how will the function even compile, and how will it be optimally moved?

Comment: @SexyBeast simple. The function takes an object of type A, thus such an object is constructed. And since you passed an A&&, the move-constructor can be used for that. Generally speaking, what you pass as concrete parameter, will be used to initialise the corresponding formal parameter of the function, possibly using any conversions applicable at that point