# C++ explicit constructor and cast

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, explicit

In the book Effective C++, Item 27

```
class Widget {
public:
explicit Widget(int size);
...
};
void doSomeWork(const Widget& w);
doSomeWork(Widget(15)); // create Widget from int
                        // with function-style cast
```

I'm not sure exactly what is happening when doSomeWork is called. I think the parameter w of function doSomeWork is initialized by another Widget object using copy constructor, but where is the other Widget object? Is it a temporary object created by casting as indicated by the comments? Can anyone tell me in details what have been called when doSomeWork function parameter is initialized?

Comment: Think about this: isn't your "function-style cast" just a call to `Widget`'s constructor?

Comment: This is what confused me. I think the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter, `w`, of function `doSomeWork` is a `Widget` that you have created as a parameter in the line

`doSomeWork(Widget(15));`

`doSomeWork` expected a `Widget` and one has been explicitly supplied using the constructor you have listed. No compiler supplied copy constructor is used because the `doSomeWork(const Widget &w)` signature uses pass by reference semantics.

Just one object is constructed, although pass-by-value could have been used and clever modern compilers would defer the construction to the method's scope to avoid duplicated construction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, yes this is pass by reference, so no copy constructor is involved. So can I say what happens is:   const Widget& w=Widget(15)  when the function is called?parameter w is initialized with an object created by Widget(15), there is no temporary object generated here.

Comment: Yes, I was just adding pass-by-value is often optimized away by compilers. In the case of the code you have posted just one object is created. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828074/passing-rvalue-reference-to-const-lvalue-reference-paremeter for a discussion on pass-by-reference and rvalues

Comment: One more question:  how about statement `Widget w=Widget(15);` in this case is a temporary object created first by Widget(15), then w is initialized by the copy constructor?

Comment: I think it depends on compiler support, better ones being smart enough to defer construction until the scope of `w`. While your example is clearly contrived to create 2 objects and test this idea it is obviously human-fixable. The compiler optimisation is called copy_elision http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision